# Рандом по процентам

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Вообщем у меня пришла идейка сделать для бота в вк рулетку, ну я сделал с обычным рандомам и понял что цифра 3 выпадает слишком часто, это зелёная, можно как то сделать что бы она выпадала с вероятностью маленькой?

```
    if (cmd.lower().startswith("рулетка")):
        try:
            c, i, a = cmd.lower().split()
            i = str(i)
            a = int(a)
        except ValueError:
            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)

            return await msg.answer(" .азино рулетка [цвет] (черный, красный, зеленый) [ставка] - сыграть в рулетку на указанную сумму.")   

        except Exception:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()

            self.current.remove(msg)
            return await msg.answer("Произошла ошибка.")

        if i == "черный" or i == "чёрный":
            stavka = 1
            vivod = ""
        elif i == "красный":
            stavka = 2
            vivod = "❤"
        elif i == "зеленый" or i == "зелёный":
            stavka = 3
            vivod = ""
        elif i == i:
            return await msg.answer(" Ты ввел неверный цвет доступные цвета (черный, красный, зеленый)")                               

        bett = a

        if bett < self.min_bet:
            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)
            return await msg.answer(" Минимальная ставка: 5.00$")

        if bett > 10000000:
            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)
            return await msg.answer(" Ставка, не больше чем 10.000.000$.")    

        if p.balance - bett < 0:
            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)
            return await msg.answer(f" У вас не хватает средств!\n Наличные: {round(p.balance, 2)}$")    

        p, _ = await self.pwmanager.get_or_create(self.player, user_id=msg.user_id)

        text = ""

        vivod2 = ""       

        for _ in range(10):
            b = random.randrange(1, 100)
            if stavka == 3 and b <= 5:
                vivod2 = ""
                text += f"➕ Тебе повезло! Ты выбрал {vivod}, и я выбрала {vivod}, ты получаешь " + str(bett * 10) + "$ (x10)"

                p.balance += bett * 10
            elif stavka == 2 and b >= 40:
                vivod2 = "❤"
                text += f"➕ Тебе повезло! Ты выбрал {vivod}, и я выбрала {vivod}, ты получаешь " + str(bett * 2) + "$ (x2)"

                p.balance += bett * 2
            elif stavka == 1 and b >= 50:
                vivod2 = ""
                text += f"➕ Тебе повезло! Ты выбрал {vivod}, и я выбрала {vivod}, ты получаешь " + str(bett * 2) + "$ (x2)"

                p.balance += bett * 2
            else:
                text += f"➖ Ха! Тебе не повезло! Ты выбрал {vivod}, а я выбрала {vivod2}, ты теряешь " + str(bett) + "$"

                p.balance -= bett    

        text += f"\n Наличные: {round(p.balance, 2)}$"    


        await self.pwmanager.update(p)
        self.current.remove(msg.user_id)

        return await msg.answer(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант задавать сразу проверку `if`ов как проценты (т.е. если `b < 5%`) и т.д.

```
import random
for _ in range(10):
    b = random.randrange(1, 100)
    if b <= 5:
        print('зеленный', b)
    elif 5 < b <= 30:
        print('желтый', b)
    else:
        print('красный', b)
```

вывод:

```
желтый 20
красный 50
зеленный 4
зеленный 1
красный 71
красный 44
красный 48
желтый 10
красный 87
зеленный 4
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Блин, там получается вакханалия он все тексты прибавляет, я обновил код как сделал подскажите что не так(

Comment: @Daeeros `for `уберите он тут для примера что несколько значений выдало

Comment: Все понял, благодарю